# sql insert into self (copy existing rows) & increment foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to copy all existing rows in a table:

```
 INSERT INTO tbl (file_id, data) SELECT file_id, data FROM tbl
```

However I want to add a value to file_id so the inserted ones have an offset

Comment: `INSERT INTO tbl (file_id, data) SELECT file_id + 1000, data FROM tbl`

Comment: What is the point of adding 1000 in particular?  There will still be conflicts with the `file_id` of the first table if it has more than 1000 records.

Comment: It was just an example. (I do that all the time when generating sample data.) OP hasn't specified the requirements very well. "An offset", or "continue from current max file_id".